IRF9540N P-MOSFET Heating UP


simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
Hello, so I am trying to make a solenoid based injector driver circuit capable of ramping current from 0 to 17A within 100us and then dropping it down to 7A to sustain injection process for 1.8ms. I am using IRF9540 P channel MOSFET to switch high and low voltage supply. The MOSFETs are heating up after 50 continuous injections, despite them being rated for 100V and 23A of continuous supply. What could be possible solution?
P.S. I have tried my luck with N-channel MOSFETs using gate driver but the inductive kickback tends to overcharge bootstrap capacitor to make it worse and hence I am only focused on using P-channel MOSFETS

What did the results from simulation look like? You did a simulation didn't you?

Simulations were fine, its just that when I did experimental investigations, the MOSEFTs start to heat up.

I'll put money on the fact that a proper simulation would have told you there were watts being dissipated in the MOSFETs.

(power dissipation per second would be a rate of chane in power dissipation.)

My bad, power dissipation was 50mW for high side MOSFET and 300mW for low side.

Take a look at these figures from the IRF9540 datasheet:

They show significant \$V_{DS}\$ when passing 7A or 17A of drain current \$I_D\$, perhaps beyond 1.5V when it gets really hot.
Initially from cold, assuming \$V_{DS}=0.5V\$ and \$I_D=7A\$, that thing is dissipating:
$$ P = I \times V = 7A \times 0.5V = 3.5W $$
As it heats though, \$V_{DS}\$ rises through 1.5V (at 175°C) and beyond, dissipating:
$$ P = I \times V = 7A \times 1.5V \approx 10W $$
It gets worse as temperature continues to rise, in thermal runaway. The transistor might be fine for a short burst of 17A, but the longer term 7A is going to burn that transistor up, unless you slap a big heatsink on it, and probably a fan.

Any suggestion, mosfet that might be helpful?

My MOSFET went from 25 degrees to 30 degrees (as measured from IR gun) after few injections. Also, the 7A is not continuous. The MOSFET is switched on and off (4us on and 6us off) for 1.8 ms to keep the avergae current around 7A.

The diodes are far too slow .Use some shottkies to eliminate this possibility. Now calculate the power wasted in the on resistance ,ignore the 23 Amp rating .You will be up for a heatsink or lots of devices in parallel.

Are you talking about shottkies for N-Channel MOSFETs? I tried with MUR1660CT but didn't improve anything.
